# Solve $\begin{cases}x\equiv-4\pmod {17}\\ x\equiv 3\pmod{23} \end{cases}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Solve $$\begin{cases}x\equiv-4\pmod {17}\\
> x\equiv 3\pmod{23}
> \end{cases}$$

**My attempt:**

$$\gcd (17,23)=1$$

so using the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)
 there is a solution modulo $17\times 23=391$

$$x=-4+17t\\
\Longrightarrow-4+17t\equiv 3\pmod{23}\\
\Longrightarrow -4+17t\equiv 3+23k\\
k,t\in \mathbb Z$$

I am stuck here

Comment: If we want to do it by fooling around with numbers, it will be useful to note that $(-4)(17)+(3)(23)=1$.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see how does it help

Comment: If we use your approach, we want $17t\equiv 7\pmod{23}$. Multiply by $-4$. We get $t\equiv -28\pmod{23}$, So $t\equiv 18\pmod{23}$. But maybe you are expected to find the answer by using a general procedure.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did but I think that the final answer should be modulo $17\times 23.\qquad\qquad x=\text{ some number }\pmod{391}$

Comment: I was using your method. You had $x=-4+17t$, so we get that $x=-4+(17)(18)$ is a solution. I think that's $302$. So the general solution is $x\equiv 302\pmod{391}$. But as I wrote, maybe you are expected to use the general Chinese Remainder Theorem algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you obtain the equivalence $-4 + 17t \equiv 3 \pmod{23}$, you can add $4$ to each side of the equivalence to obtain 
$$17t \equiv 7 \pmod{23}$$
Since $\gcd(17, 23) = 1$, this equivalence has a solution. To solve it, we can apply the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find the multiplicative inverse of $17$ modulo $23$, then multiply both sides of the equivalence $17t \equiv 7 \pmod{23}$ by that inverse.
\begin{align*}
23 & = 1 \cdot 17 + 6\\
17 & = 2 \cdot 6 + 5\\
6 & = 1 \cdot 5 + 1\\
5 & = 5 \cdot 1
\end{align*}
Now, we work backwards to solve for $1$ in terms of $17$ and $23$.
\begin{align*}
1 & = 6 - 5\\
  & = 6 - (17 - 2 \cdot 6)\\
  & = 3 \cdot 6 - 17\\
  & = 3(23 - 17) - 17\\
  & = 3 \cdot 23 - 4 \cdot 17
\end{align*}
Thus, $-4 \cdot 17 = 1 - 3 \cdot 23 \implies -4 \cdot 17 \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$.  Multiplying both sides of the equivalence 
$$17t \equiv 7 \pmod{23}$$
by $-4$ yields
\begin{align*}
-4 \cdot 17t & \equiv -4 \cdot 7 \pmod{23}\\
t & \equiv -28 \pmod{23}\\
t & \equiv -28 + 2 \cdot 23 \pmod{23}\\
t & \equiv 18 \pmod{23}
\end{align*}
Hence, $t = 18 + 23n$ for some integer $n$.  Substituting this value for $t$ into the expression $x = -4 + 17t$ yields
\begin{align*} 
x & = -4 + 17(18 + 23n)\\ 
  & = -4 + 306 + 17 \cdot 23n\\ 
  & = 302 + 391n
\end{align*} 
Thus, $x \equiv 302 \pmod{391}$, the result Andre Nicolas obtained in the comments by making an astute observation.

**Check:**  Observe that 
\begin{align*}
302 & = 17 \cdot 18 - 4 \implies 302 \equiv -4 \pmod{17}\\
302 & = 13 \cdot 23 + 3 \implies 302 \equiv 3 \pmod{23}
\end{align*}