# Solve $\begin{cases}x\equiv 1\pmod{5}\\x\equiv0\pmod{66}\\x\equiv6\pmod 7\end{cases}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules

> Solve $$\begin{cases}
> x\equiv 1\pmod{5}\,\,\,\qquad\qquad.1\\
> x\equiv0\pmod{66}\qquad\qquad.2\\
> x\equiv6\pmod 7\,\,\,\qquad\qquad.3
> \end{cases}$$

**My attempt:**

$\gcd(66,5,7)=1$ so I can apply the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

From $.1$:

$$x\equiv 1+5y$$

$.1$ in $.2$:

$$x\equiv1+5y\equiv0\pmod{66}$$

$$\Longrightarrow 5y\equiv-1\pmod{66}$$

$$\Longrightarrow y\equiv13+66k$$

from $.3$:

$$x\equiv6+7y$$

$$\Longrightarrow x\equiv6+7(13+66k)$$

$$x\equiv 97+462k$$

from $.1$:

$$x\equiv 1+5(97+462k)$$

$$x\equiv 1+485+2310k$$

$$\bbox[yellow]{x\equiv 486\pmod{2310}}$$

But the answer should be $x\equiv 1056 \pmod{2310}$

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

Comment: Yes, I need to use this theorem

Comment: "from 3 x = 6 + 7y"... uh, what?  6 = 6 + 7m for *some* m but why would it be the number 7 from 2?

Comment: I am not sure about what I did I tried to do the same as [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1795579/306803) @fleablood

Comment: $486 \equiv 3\pmod 7$ while the number sought should give $6$, and $486 \equiv 24\pmod 66$ while you need to get $0$. So possibly you can plug $486$ for $x$ in all your congruences and check which are not satisfied. There you should find a mistake.

Comment: You shouldn't have done $x = 6 + 7y$ as you have no reason to assume that $x = 6 + 7m; m = y?????$.  You should have done $x = 66 + 330k = 6 mod 7$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have that $x=5k+1$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$ by your first equation.

Then, $5k+1\equiv 0\  (\mathrm{mod}\ 66)$, so, as you said in the second part, $k\equiv 13+66q \ (\mathrm{mod}\ 66)$.

Now $x=5k+1=5(13+66q)+1=66+330q$.

Finally you use the third equation ($66\equiv 3$ and $330\equiv 1$ both mod $7$): $x\equiv -1 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ 7)$, so

$$x=66+330q\equiv 3+q\equiv -1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 7)$$

so $q\equiv -4\equiv 3 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ 7)$, that means that $q=7r+3$, so returning to the original equation, you get that

$$x=5k+1=5(13+66q)+1=330q+66=330(7r+3)+66=2310r+990+66=2310r+1056$$

So yes, you're right, the answer is $x\equiv 1056 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ 2310)$.